# Smtp error (454) authentication failed

Tags: server, email, thunderbird, postfix

Ubuntu
20.04
contabo VPS
virtualmin/webmin panel
postfix+Dovecot

domain is redirected from cloudflare- maybe missing any records (not sure…)
A   mail    ip address
A   webmail     ip address
MX  domainname.com  mail.domainname.com 1

I want to send and get emails
Installed roundcube + want to access via thunderbird

Created new user (virtualmin/edit users)

```
#1 When I login to roundcube I can only get emails and if I try to send the error pops out:

“**smtp error (454) authentication failed**”

#2 Thunderbird does not connect at all with the settings from “Email Client Settings”
```

The only way If I go to Webmin/ Read user mail/ then I can read or send an email or using “usermin”

Just opened terminal and checked ports on the current virtual server administrator name

```
netstat -tulpan
```

these ports needed for email seems to be open
IMAP
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:993 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

pop3
tcp6 0 0 :::995 :::* LISTEN

smpt
tcp6 0 0 :::587 :::* LISTEN

port 25
tcp6 0 0 :::25 :::* LISTEN

How to fix this?

Comment: which kind of sasl authentication do you use? what IMAP/POP server did you install ?
could you please show us the following:
stmpd_relay_restrictions,
smtpd_recipient_restrictions,
the submission daemon paramaters (in master.cf)
and of course, the relevant log when you try to send emails.

Comment: I had to hire a dedicated person to sort this out. It is working now. Just could not wait for a month for someone to answer.

Comment: @peakminute any chance of posting your configs?